# Legends of colors with ListPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm taking this example in the documentation :

```
ListPlot[Table[
  Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]
```

[image]

I'd like to write a colored PlotLegend (like in a DensityPlot) for this plot of this style :

[image]

and associate it with a value that would be for example :

```
Table[t/(2 Pi), {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}]
```

Remark: Actually, it would be sufficient for me to plot a density plot with those values and the plot legends with the same hues as in the ListPlot, and I would copy-past this colored legend. But I also don't know how to do that.

Comment: `ListPlot[Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}], PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 1}}]]` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
legend1 = BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 2 Pi}}];

ListPlot[Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}], 
    PlotLegends -> legend1]
```

[image]

Also

```
Legended[ListPlot[Table[Style[{Cos[t], Sin[2 t]}, Hue[t/(2 Pi)]], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}]], 
 Placed[legend1, Right]]
```

> same picture